# Zip_Longest Returning One Result

Tags: python

in my confirmAck function I am trying to use the file_date_l list in my SQL query. The thing is its only returning one "file_date_l". When i do a seperate for loop that is not in my zip_longest then it returns 3 or 4 results. Why is it that when i use it with zip_longest it returns only one query?

results:

```
select * from sendfile where processingdate = '    2020/12/07' and 
        paymenttotamt = 123.20 and datasetname like '%FILENAME%'
```

expected results:

```
select * from sendfile where processingdate = '    2020/12/07' and 
        paymenttotamt = 123.20 and datasetname like '%FILENAME%' 

select * from sendfile where processingdate = '    2020/12/07' and 
        paymenttotamt = 123.20 and datasetname like '%FILENAME%' 
select * from sendfile where processingdate = '    2020/12/07' and 
        paymenttotamt = 123.20 and datasetname like '%FILENAME%'
```

code edited:

```
def scrapeBOAWebsite(gp_url, gp_subject_l)


    icl_dollar_amount_l = []
    file_date_l = []

    for gp in gp_url_l:
        options = Options()
        options.add_argument('--headless')
        options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
        options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
        options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)
        browser = webdriver.Chrome(options=options,
                                   executable_path=r'\\TEST\user$\bxt058y\Documents\driver\chromedriver.exe')
        browser.get(gp)
        body = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'Total:')]").text
        icl_dollar_amount = re.findall('(?:[\£\$\€]{1}[,\d]+.?\d*)', body)[0]
        icl_dollar_amount_l.append(icl_dollar_amount)
        get_company_id = body.split("Customer Id:", 1)[1]
        get_file_date = body.split("Receipt Time:", 1)[1][0:14]
        print(get_company_id)
        file_date_l.append(get_file_date)

    return icl_dollar_amount_l, file_date_l

def confirmAck(sql_server_conn, sql_server_cursor,icl_dollar_amount_l,file_date_l):

    for icl_dollar_amount,f_date in zip_longest(icl_dollar_amount_l, file_date_l):
        get_sendfile_details_q = f"""select * from sendfile where processingdate = '{f_date}' and 
        paymenttotamt = {str(icl_dollar_amount).replace(',', '').replace('$', '')} and datasetname like '%FILENAME%' """

        get_sendfile_details_q_results = sql_server_cursor.execute(get_sendfile_details_q).fetchall()

        print(get_sendfile_details_q)

icl_dollar_amount_l, file_date_l = scrapeBOAWebsite(gp_url_l, gp_subject_l)
confirmAck(sql_server_conn, sql_server_cursor, icl_dollar_amount_l, file_date_l)
```

Comment: What is `(icl_dollar_amount_l, file_date_l)`? That information would help others to see what is going on here. The code that you posted isn't a [mcve] so isn't all that helpful.

Comment: @JohnColeman Sorry just made the edit

Comment: What are the actual values in those lists in an example where you find the output problematic? I suspect that the problem is down-stream from `zip_longest`, perhaps traceable to the absence of a non-default `fillvalue`.

Comment: @JohnColeman If i actual do a seperate for loop for file_date_l then I get like 3 dates '12/7/2020',12/7/2020',12/7/2020'. I get only one 12/7/2020 if i mix it with the zip_longest.

Comment: You are telling us what happens when you use `zip_longest` but you haven't provided an actual example which others can use as a [mcve]. Something like `icl_dollar_amount_l = [ ... ] #with values you provide` and `file_date_l = [ ... ] #etc.` It would help if you gave two concrete lists for which `zip_longest` doesn't work as advertised.